# Given a BLDC motor with one shaft, where should I attach my encoder?

Tags: motors

I have recently purchased an ODrive servo controller made for hobby BLDC motors.  Since I had a BLDC motor at home, I did not purchase a dual shaft motor when I got the ODrive.

My question is if I am to use this BDLC motor as a servo, which side should I affix the encoder to, and which side should I affix to the axis I am planning to rotate (the load)?  I have an 8mm shaft on one side and I have a plate with 4 threaded holes on the other side, and need to choose.  I can 3d print anything needed but do not have access to any milling machine or lathe.

Here you can see the two parts of the motor, along with the 8mm shaft on one end.  The "STATOR" is on top.  The "ROTOR" is on the bottom.
[image]

Here you see the back side of the motor (the "ROTOR"), and note that the shaft does not extend sufficiently to mount something to it, but that there are 4 threaded holes where something can be fixed.

[image]

Here are a couple encoders I have access to (just as FYI, not necessarily the focus of the question).  They are a SICK industrial style and a CUI amt102-v rotary encoder:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, I am assuming that the 4 holes are there to mount some sort of propeller, so I guess thats where I should try to affix my load.  I still don't know what the right choice is and dont think I can ever mount the load perfectly on axis but I can try as best I can and even make whatever I use have an press fit with that circle in the middle of the plate.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the motor?

Comment: Rotate a lightweight arm (direct drive) for an acoustic test setup.  <180 degrees of motion..